# SQL query change the two front number from "2048" to "1948"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a date that looks like this in DB **"2048-05-21"**

I want to get the year only and in the year I want to get two back number only and change the two front number to 19

> **example:**
>
> data : 2048-05-21
>
> 1st result : 2048
>
> 2nd result : 48
>
> 3rd result : 1948
>
> 4th result: 1948-05-21

can SQL do it?

Comment: Your question should be how can I do rather than can sql do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. the first result  `year` function.
2. the second result `year` function with `SUBSTR` function.
3. the third result  `DATE_ADD` minus 100 years then use `year` function.
4. the fourth result `DATE_ADD` minus 100 years

You can try this.

```
SELECT year(col),
       SUBSTR(year(col), 3, 2),
       year(DATE_ADD(col,INTERVAL -100 YEAR)),
       DATE_ADD(col,INTERVAL -100 YEAR)
FROM T
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3dd6f/8

**Result**

```
|    1 |  2 |    3 |          4 |
|------|----|------|------------|
| 2048 | 48 | 1948 | 1948-05-21 |
```

Comment: No problem :) Glad to help

Answer (score 2):

Is
`select year(your_column)-100 from your_table`
sufficent? I assume that your "date" has a column typ of date or datetime. Otherwise you must use substring (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring.asp)

Comment: yaa its true the data type is date but why get 1812 instead of 1912 ?

Comment: What was your date in the first place? If you have a year 1999 and you substract 100, you get 1899. Maybe you have to adjust the value 100 for your needs...

Comment: my date is 2048-05-21  but actually the data is 1948-05-21 i dont know why its change to 2048..

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @date DATE ='2048-05-21'

SELECT CAST(CAST(year(@date)-100 AS VARCHAR) + SUBSTRING(CAST(@date AS VARCHAR),5,6) AS DATE)
```

Comment: Could you add a little bit of an explanation on why and how your code provides an answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Hi below are the sql queries based on your query

declare @date date --declaring the date variable
set @date='2048-05-21' --intializing the date

--First Result
select **year(@date)**

--Second Result 
select **substring(Convert(varchar,year(@date)),3,2 )**

--Third Result
select **year(@date)-100**

--Fourth Result
select **DATEFROMPARTS (year(@date)-100 , month(@date), day(@date))**